# Registering a class with Kryo via twitter chill-scala

Tags: scala, serialization, kryo

I'm trying to serialize an instance of a Scala class using Kryo via Twitter's chill-scala library.  It's from a library (external jar) and thus, I think, needs to be registered with Kryo.

How do I register a class to (de)serialize using chill-scala?

Here's the core of my code, based mostly on examining the chill-scala test suite.

```
// This is from the chill-scala test suite
def serialize[T](t: T): Array[Byte] = ScalaKryoInstantiator.defaultPool.toBytesWithClass(t)
def deserialize[T](bytes: Array[Byte]): T =
  ScalaKryoInstantiator.defaultPool.fromBytes(bytes).asInstanceOf[T]


/**
 * Save a value in cache.
 */
def save[T](key: String, value: T, expiration: Int = 0): Future[T] = {
  cache.put(key, serialize[T](value), expiration, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  Future.successful(value)
}

/**
 * Finds a value in the cache.
 */
def find[T: ClassTag](key: String): Future[Option[T]] = Future {
  val result = deserialize[T](cache.get(key).asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]])
  Option(result)
}
```

When I run it, it throws

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: <name_of_external_class>
```

More generally, is there documentation someplace on how to use chill-scala?  The authors of that package have obviously done a substantial amount of work and I've seen a number of positive references to it -- but no documentation.

Thanks for any pointers,

Byron

Answer (score 0):

I believe that chill is just an extension to Kryo, which provides serializers for supported scala classes better than the Kryo default `FieldSerializer`.

So, if you do not know how to use chill, you should try to read [the docs of Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo).

And, the exception of

```
Unable to find class: <name_of_external_class>
```

is probably because the class is not in your class path. It may not relate to Kryo.

Note that, even not registered in Kryo, the class can still be serialized by Kryo.

If you need good example of using chill, source code of [Apache Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark) is a good choice. Also, the small example in [this repo](https://github.com/xitrum-framework/chill-scala) is acceptable.